# How to correctly read and encode a text sent via flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, unicode, python-unicode

I wrote a simple API that reads and writes files. A minimal version is below:

```
import flask

class Web:

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = flask.Flask('web')
        self.app.add_url_rule('/read/<filename>', 'read', self.read)
        self.app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=6543)

    def read(self, filename: str):
        return open(filename).read()  

Web()
```

Consider the following file (the one that will be read). It is saved as `UTF-8` in Windows Notepad:

```
ascii
éàçèïê
```

When trying to download it via curl:

```
PS > curl http://localhost:6543/read/c5f89f95ef49492c82bdbcc133a5c567
ascii
Ã©Ã Ã§Ã¨Ã¯Ãª
```

I tried to redirect it to a file, it is a mess as well:

[image]

It looks like that somewhere in the chain "read file with `open()`" → "return it via flask" I made a mistake in encoding/decoding Unicode magic.

Comment: try `curl -D` and check what charset is set in content-type header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this construction:

```
open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```